# How to use coroutines to detect if the player is still for long enough

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I am not very good with coroutines and am trying to make something in my game. My goal is to make it so if the player stays still for a certain amount of seconds (in this case, 3), it will call a function. I am trying to use coroutines, but I have not been able to make them work. Here is my code so far:

```cs
...
public float waitTime;

void Update()
{
   if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E) && rb.velocity.x <= stillVelocity.x && rb.velocity.y <= stillVelocity.y)
   {
       StartCoroutine(coroutine());
   }
   else
   {
       StopCoroutine(coroutine());
   }
}
IEnumerator coroutine()
{
   yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
   method();
}
void method()
{
   Debug.Log("It all worked");
}
```

I did manage to get the "It all worked" in my log, but not the way I intended it. It would print it even if I had let go of E before the *waitTime* had passed. The velocity checking works fine.

Now, I should probably say what I wanted the script to do. I wanted the script to detect if the player is still and they are holding the E key down for *waitTime* seconds. How this will apply to an actual game is this: I am making a system where the player can raise a checkpoint. This checkpoint is the spawnpoint from then on until a new checkpoint is created. I can do the checkpoint/spawnpoint thing on my own, and only need help with coroutines.

I may be wrong with the idea of using coroutines. I chose to use them in this case because I heard that I should use them when my code works with time. I also think I need to practice using them more to get a better understanding of them.

---

Here are my questions:

- Am I right in use coroutines here?
- If so, how would I use the coroutines?
- If not, when should I use them?

(Please use coroutines in your answer unless it is **absolutely impossible** to do it without them. I would prefer this, because I can do it without the coroutines, but, as said above, I need the practice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Coroutine` can work here, but as you are just wanting to call a function after a certain amount of time, an `Involke` might work better. I tend to use `Involke` whenever I just need a function called after X seconds, but use a `Coroutine` when I need to create a function that runs based on a series of preconditions in a specific way or after a specific amount of time.

The one issue I currently see with your code is you are continually calling `StartCoroutine` without checking if the `Coroutine` is active. Whenever I need to use a `Coroutine` with conditions that can occur multiple times in the lifetime of the actual `Coroutine`, I will store a reference and check if the reference is null.

```
...
public float waitTime;

private Coroutine YourCoroutineReference = null;

void Update()
{
   if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E) && rb.velocity.x <= stillVelocity.x && rb.velocity.y <= stillVelocity.y)
   {
       if(YourCoroutineReference == null)
           YourCoroutineReference = StartCoroutine(coroutine());
   }
   else
   {
       if(YourCoroutineReference != null)
            StopCoroutine(YourCoroutineReference);
   }
}
IEnumerator coroutine()
{
   yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
   method();
   YourCoroutineReference = null;
}
void method()
{
   Debug.Log("It all worked");
}
```

With this additional conditional check, the printout should work as intended. I would however use an invoke here instead as your use case is triggering a singular method after a fixed amount of time.

Here is the example using `Invoke`

```
...
public float waitTime;

void Update()
{
   if (!IsInvoking("method") && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E) && rb.velocity.x <= stillVelocity.x && rb.velocity.y <= stillVelocity.y)
   {
       Invoke("method", waitTime);
   }
   else
   {
       if(IsInvoking("method"))
       {
           CancelInvoke("method");
       }
   }
}

private void method()
{
   Debug.Log("It all worked");
}
```

Both snippets are untested, but the general direction is there. If you run into an issue let me know and I can update the snippets. Again, if you find yourself just using `Coroutine` to call a function after a certain time, use an `Invoke`. When doing anything more complex where you are laying out multiple function calls or Lerps in succession, a `Coroutine` is a very useful tool for that.

I will also add that `Coroutines` are very flexible in that you can pause them for any reason using `yields` then continue them, whereas an `Invoke` is generally called once after X seconds, or called every Y seconds after X seconds if you use `InvokeRepeating`. Another useful part of using `Coroutines` is you can pass parameters to them where with `Invoke`, you can not. I suppose an oversimplified way to think about it is `Invoke` is a very simple general case for single use `Coroutines` or extremely fixed time repeating methods.

Comment: Thanks. I have heard of `Invoke` before, but didn’t know about the rest of the invoke variables like IsInvoking. Thanks for your help. I will be able to test this sometime in the afternoon, then I can Mark you answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the coroutine to instead of waiting, constantly check if player is still and call after 3 seconds, else break.

```cs
IEnumerator coroutine()
{
    float limit = 3;
    float elapsed = 0;
    while(elapsed < limit)
    {
        if(!IsPlayerStill())
        {
            yield break;
        }
        elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
   
    method();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `Update` check anyway actually I wouldn't use a Coroutine here but rather a simple counter like

```
float timer;
bool alreadyFired;

void Update()
{
   if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E) && rb.velocity.x <= stillVelocity.x && rb.velocity.y <= stillVelocity.y)
   {
       timer -= Time.deltaTime;

       if(!alreadyFired && timer <= 0)
       {
           alreadyFired = true;
           method();
       }
   }
   else
   {
       alreadyFired = false;
       timer = waitTime;
   }
}
```

In this use case I think this would be way easier to maintain than a coroutine.

If you really want to go for a Coroutine I would do it like

```
private Coroutine _routine;

void Update()
{
   if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E) && rb.velocity.x <= stillVelocity.x && rb.velocity.y <= stillVelocity.y)
   {
       if(_routine == null) _routine = StartCoroutine(DoAfterSeconds(waitTime, method));
   }
   else
   {
       if(_routine != null) StopCoroutine(_routine);

        _routine = null;
   }
}

private IEnumerator DoAfterSeconds (float duration, Action callback)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (duration);

    _routine = null;

    callback?.Invoke();
}
```